# UICollectionView in UINavgationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, collectionview

I want to do a simple example.

I have a `rootViewController` that is a `UINavgationController`, and there is a `UIViewController` in that `UINavgationController`. Now I want to create `UICollectionView` in the `UIViewController`, but I am getting an error.

here is the code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "XJViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    XJViewController *xjv = [[XJViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:xjv];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface XJViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

@end

#import "XJViewController.h"

@interface XJViewController ()

@end

@implementation XJViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.title = @"XJ";

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    NSDictionary *dicColor = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = dicColor;

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *fLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];

    UICollectionView *cv = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:fLayout];


    [cv registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myeCell"];

    cv.dataSource = self;
    cv.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:cv];

}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return cell;
}
```

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view
>   of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier myCell - must
>   register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype
>   cell in a storyboard'

Please help me figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
[cv registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myeCell"];
```

The identifier here is different from the one you are using in -cellForItemAtIndexPath